# What is the maximum length of a Tezos domain?

Tags: validation

When validating a Tezos domain, such as `example.tez` is the maximum length of the address (excl `.tez`) 249 characters (upper domain limit is 253 chars) or is it 63 characters (the upper limit on subdomains)?

Does the following Tezos domain regex cover all use cases?

```
/[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]{2,63}\.[a-z]{3}/
```

Comment: can you describe the use case? if you're trying to check if an address is valid, don't add extra validation - just use the tezos-domains client packages https://gitlab.com/tezos-domains/client/-/blob/master/README.md

Comment: the use case doesn't matter, but in this instance the regex pattern is for frontend form validation before submitting a request to a contract, and a max length check inside the contract that accepts a domain string parameter

Comment: additionally, if it is possible to register domains of 64+ characters then does this have an impact on the `.tez.page` ipfs file hosting functionality?

Comment: **update** i registered a 100 character long domain and can confirm it breaks hosting when wallet name is longer than 63 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends what you want to use the domain for.

If you want to use the built in `.tez.page` hosting that is included with all Tezos domains there is a technical limit of 63 characters and subdomains are not allowed.

Domains longer than this are not compatible with the hosting functionality as they exceed the maximum length for a subdomain in a URL.

```
/[A-Za-z0-9_\-]{2,63}\.[a-z]{3}/
```

If you do not need or want the hosting functionality then you can register domains of up to 100 characters in length.

```
/[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]{2,100}\.[a-z]{3}/
```

*note*

The `.tez` is not hardcoded into the regex so that the testnet domains also pass validation.